# How to scale buttons for different devices

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have buttons on my screen I have attached constraints but on different sizes of screen I don't see my buttons right as I want to. There are the same size on different screens and I can't see all buttons on small screens

Here is a good version of it on iphone 8 plus in xcode

[image]

and then I change view to iphone se or any another iphone and I get these troubles:

[image: image2]

What do I need to do to have the same screens?

Answer (score 2):

- Make the buttons have a width that is in proportion to the view
  width.
- Then add a 1:1 aspect ratio constant so that the buttons remain
  square.
- Then position the buttons in relation to the screen dimensions (not
  absolutely).

This should get the job done for you.

**Setting proportional width**

Suppose the main view's dimension is 375 x 667 in interface builder. Suppose you place a 90 x 90 button on it. To make it always have a width in proportion to the main view's width,

1. Add an equal widths constraint to the superview for the button.
2. Edit the constraint's multiplier: Change it from 1 to (90/375)

Doing the above makes sure that for different screen widths, the button's width will also change in proportion.

Here are screen shots from iPhone XR and iPhone 5s, that I took from a sample I just did to try this out. As you can see, the buttons stay within the screen and maintain their shape. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! How can i do the first step - "Make the buttons have a width that is in proportion to the view height." ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Also I did it for width, not height (my bad :( )

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have defined the constraints of the button to superview. eg: left edge, top edge...

*edit: post complaint below #raisedeybrow
You will need to define (add constraints) how far from the edge (left and top, right and bottom) you want your button/s to be. Then apply content hugging and compression priorities on buttons for all of them to scale as you'd like. Some will need to be bigger, some you don't want to allow to shrink etc. Lots to set if you'd want it to look fluid

Comment: This section is for answers only.

Comment: Well, seeing that there are no constraints defined on the screenshot and providing the option to set leading (left edge) and top edge constraints would imply an answer in which direction to go to solve it, wouldn't it? I guess we'll spoon feed everyone, why not &shrug;